# Training dataset repeatedly - Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am doing an image classification task using Keras.

I used the vgg16 architecture, I thought it is easier to do, the task is to classify the image having tumor or not in MRI images.

As usual, I read and make all the images in same shape (224×224×3) and normalised by dividing all the images by 255. Then train test split, test dataset is 25% and training dataset is 75%.

```
train, test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)
```

Then, I trained and got val_loss as 0.64 and val_accuracy as 0.7261.
I save the trained model in my google drive.

Next day, I used the same procedure, to improve the model performance by loading the saved model.

I didn't change the model architecture, I simply loaded the saved model which scores 0.7261 accuracy.

This time, I got better performance, the val_loss is 0.58 and val_accurqcy is 0.7976.

I wonder how this gets high accuracy. Then, I found that when splitting the dataset, the images will splits in random, and thus some of the test data in the 1st training process will become training data in the 2nd training process. So, the model learns the images and predicted well in 2nd training process.

I have to clarify, is this model is truly learns the tumor patterns or it is like that we train and test the model with same dataset or same image samples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using `train_test_split` and validating in different sessions, always set your random seed. Otherwise, you will be using different splits, and leaking data like you stated. The model is not "learning" more, rather is being validated on data that it has already trained on. You will likely get worse real-world performance.